# Can tourists go skiing in Yemen?

Tags: skiing, yemen

Is it possible for tourists to go skiing in Yemen?

An article talking about the [skiing scene in Saudi Arabia](http://americanbedu.com/2013/03/03/no-snow-in-saudi-arabia-there-is-now-and-skiing-too/) mentions:

> Saudi entrepreneurs have seen the demand for snow sports facilities in
>   the country, and have actually attempted to build ski resorts in
>   mountainous areas of southwest Saudi Arabia, next to the border with
>   Yemen.

If the bits of Saudi Arabia near Yemen are potential targets for skiing, does that mean that skiing within Yemen is possible?

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Yemen&oldid=577039718#Sport) that it's possible to go skiing in Yemen, but doesn't provide a citation.

Criteria for skiing:

1. It has to be outdoors, not indoors like Ski Dubai
2. On snow, not sand
3. Open for tourists, not just locals

Comment: It is indoors: http://www.althawranews.net/portal/news-58343.htm

Comment: The article also mentions *the 5,000 m peaks in the region*, whereas the highest point of the peninsula is [3666 metre high](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabal_an_Nabi_Shu%27ayb).  It's not high enough for skiing.

Comment: I guess the number was rounded up by a politician from the area.. you know, they like to exaggerate things..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**

The highest mountain in Yemen (and the entire Arab peninsula) is [Jabal an Nabi Shu'aib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabal_an_Nabi_Shu%27ayb), and is 3666 metre high.  Citing Wikipedia:

> Although the summit is not snow-capped like its counterparts in northern Lebanon and Syria, there have been reports of snow on the peak and frost in the winter is there daily.

In other words, even at the highest point in Yemen snow is not ubiquitous.  Therefore, there is no outdoor snow-skiing tourist industry in Yemen.

Comment: But you could bring your own skis and keep watching the weather reports!